# linear transform for coordinates system from image domain to paper domain

Tags: python, transform

I need a linear transform for relating an image domain to a paper domain. I found an interesting paper that does almost the same I need, but they have different starting and ending cordinate system. Here is a picture:

[image]

in my case the image domain is:

- x; going from left to right.
- y; going from downwards to upwards.

and the paper domain is: (the paper domain is like this because I am using NAO robot for drawing and its coordinates system for Left Arm is like I am saying to you)

- x; going from downwards to upwards.
- y; going from left to right.

So I was trying to create a formula for the translation from my image domain to my paper domain and keep the "area" of the drawing, making use in the formula of ximin, yimin, ximax, etc.

Here is the formula (made by the guys from the paper I read):

[image]

I tried to modify it for my case, however I did not get satisfatory values, so I really believe I made a mistake in the formula. I've also changed `ypar` from the starting formula with `ypmax` in mine:

```
xp = xpmin + (((yimax-yimin)/(xpmax-xpmin))*(yimax+yi))
yp = ypmin + (((ximax-ximin)/(ypmax-ypmin))*(ximax+xi))
```

Any help of yours is highly apreciated.

Comment: "I did not get satisfatory values": What results *did* you get and what resulsts would be satisfatory?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: If you take the formulas you have and substitute "left" or "top" for "min" and "right" or "bottom" for "max" you should get the proper results.

Comment: This values are given to another formula which calculate angle of movement for upper arm and forearm. When I pass those values to the function for calculating this angle, it returns me an error: `ValueError: math domain error`. Meaning that this values are out of the domain of `math.cos` function I use. 
The Python version is 2.7, but I think does not really matter.

Comment: Are the variables of integer type?

Comment: You seem to at least have messed up the numerators of the formula. And you seem to use different naming convention in your code vs the formula posted. So atm, it's hard\impossible to help you without more information.

Comment: The variables are of `double` type. And I've updated my question so now the variables in my formula have the same names of the variables in the starting formula